# Cannot be undone because a file already exists at "tfs file path here". The file must be deleted from disk for the undo to succeed

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, gated-checkin

I have copied and paste that existing Uploads folder on same solution. I have renamed existing Uploads folder from "Uploads" to "Uploadsold". Then renamed that newly pasted(created) folder from "Uploads - Copy" to "Uploads".
Then I have Gated check-in my code on TFS without `.csproj` file. Committed was successfully.

But here after I could not check in any changes.
Whenever try to commit, cannot be undone because a `file already exists at tfs file path here. The file must be deleted from disk for the undo to succeed`.
Even I have rollback whole changeset but still exists same error?

Comment: What's the source control type do you use? TFVC or Git?

Comment: Hi @AndyLi-MSFT . source control is TFVC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try below things to narrow down the issue:

- Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path should be
  like this: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\{version}\Cache.`
- Rename the file under the specific path to something else (e.g:
  `test.config`  to `newtest.config`), then check it again.
- Clone a new local Git repository if you are using Git. Create and map
  a new workspace for TFVC if you are using TFVC, then try it again.

---

**UPDATE:**

For the issue in get source step, just try to set `clean` to `true` and select `source directory` as the clean option in your build definition, then try it again.

Seems it's related to the temp workspace which created during the build process. So, if that still not work, then try to change another agent for building or clean caches and restart the build agent server, check if that works.

Comment: I tried you said that above method.but still throw an exception of "##[error]Exit code 100 returned from process: file name 'tf', arguments 'vc undo /recursive C:\agent\_work\33\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt'."

Comment: @GowthamAlan This is another error, just try to set `clean` to `true` and select `source directory` as the clean option in your build definition, then try it again.

Comment: Hi, @AndyLi-MSFT I have just restart the agent and simply Gated Check-in from another one user's Id with different workspaces. the problem was solved.
then I got the latest version from my workspace(local machine) and can able to check-in my code from my workspace too. I don't know what causes to happened this.your instruction was great.